# Passenger uses all my RAM memory and my server downs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

When I restart my server all is OK! It loads fast. But with every reload of page it fill my memory and at the end my server downs.

```
---------- Nginx processes -----------
PID    PPID   VMSize    Private  Name
--------------------------------------
18441  1      137.3 MB  0.2 MB   nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
18442  18441  137.9 MB  0.8 MB   nginx: worker process
18443  18441  137.6 MB  0.5 MB   nginx: worker process
18444  18441  138.0 MB  1.0 MB   nginx: worker process
18445  18441  137.6 MB  0.5 MB   nginx: worker process
### Processes: 5
### Total private dirty RSS: 3.11 MB


----- Passenger processes ------
PID    VMSize    Private   Name
--------------------------------
18423  218.4 MB  0.3 MB    PassengerWatchdog
18431  234.9 MB  1.1 MB    PassengerLoggingAgent
19080  567.8 MB  0.9 MB    PassengerHelperAgent
19093  461.7 MB  59.7 MB   Passenger AppPreloader: /home/rails/myapp
19108  398.6 MB  101.6 MB  Passenger RackApp: /home/rails/myapp
19160  395.7 MB  76.1 MB   Passenger RackApp: /home/rails/myapp
19168  397.8 MB  99.5 MB   Passenger RackApp: /home/rails/myapp
### Processes: 7
### Total private dirty RSS: 339.29 MB



             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           490        437         52          0         12         56
```

Comment: Try running less workers

Answer (score 1):

You should specify max count of Passenger workers:

```
passenger_min_instances 2;
passenger_max_pool_size 4;
```

Set appropriate values for these variables. [Here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerMaxPoolSize) you can find more details.

Comment: it doesn't work. The same thing again. I have just 20MB free memory

Comment: Can you show output of `sudo passenger-memory-stats` and values for variables provided above?

Comment: I add it to the question

Comment: Your application is using about 339MB now and you have 3 running workers. How many memory has your server (requires output of `free -m`)?

Comment: I have 52MB free memory just

Comment: This is your problem :) Regular size of small Rails application about 100-200MB. So, in your environment you can run 2-3 Rails workers maximum or you should increase your memory size.

Comment: Yet one question. Do you enabled swap file (requires output of `free -m`)?

Comment: `Swap:            0          0          0`  did you ask about it?

Comment: Yes, is it mean if your OS doesn't have a free memory it will **kill** fat processes (like Rails workers) for leave memory. Try to [enable swap](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04).

Comment: FYI: [Linux out-of-memory (OOM) killer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-oom-killer-decides-which-process-to-kill-first)

Comment: `Mem => 449/490MB  ||  Swp => 56/255MB` it seems does not work too =/

Comment: Lets try to check that the problem related to OOM Killer. Run `sudo grep -i kill /var/log/kern.log` it should return strings like `Out of memory: Kill process 29957 (java) score 366 or sacrifice child` in case if your workers has been killed. Probably need to use `dmesg` or `messages` logs instead of `kern.log` (depend to OS family).

Comment: I have an Ubuntu OS. And `sudo grep -i kill /var/log/kern.log` it does not help, too

Comment: Let's try to check OS, Rails, Passenger and nginx logs. May be they contains any useful information about problem.